# Using sqlcompact with how excel-dna

Tags: excel-dna

when I use sqlcompact in excel-dna,At sqlceca40.dll I could not packed xll.So I my excel.xll is not work.

Comment: my addin.dna is  <DnaLibrary Name="iPreon Add-In" RuntimeVersion="v4.0">
  <ExternalLibrary Path="D:\Alvin\GitTeam\IpreonUDF\UDF\x86\sqlceca40.dll" ExplicitExports="false" ExplicitRegistration="true" LoadFromBytes="true" Pack="true"  /></DnaLibrary>

Answer (score 1):

This is not a supported scenario by `ExcelDnaPack` at the moment.

`ExcelDnaPack` only supports packing of .NET assemblies (a.k.a. *managed* DLLs). `sqlceca40.dll` is a Win32 DLL... Therefore you won't be able to pack that DLL in your XLL using `ExcelDnaPack`.

You could use alternative approaches to embed the `sqlceca40.dll` into your add-in assembly using a tool such as [Fody.Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura), for example, as [this example in SO shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079595/costura-fody-for-a-dll-that-references-another-dll).

Comment: Thank you very much,I take away sqlcompact.I use file replace it,to cache my data.